# Create side menu wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've try to create side menu like link image below but not successful. Can help me? Sorry I don't enough reputation for add image.
Thank in advance!

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbAL6.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://slideview.codeplex.com/

This is a good third party control

Comment: Thank you for response. I try custom slideview but I can't made like image.